# How to add a linux environment variable for different language (PHP or RUBY)

Tags: php, environment-variables, ruby, web-development

I would like to add a linux environment variable for my differents applications written in PHP and Ruby.

Its goal is to differntiate between 'production' and 'development' linux environment.

**How to have an linux environment variable (ex : APPLICATION_ENV='production') that can be accessed with PHP and Ruby?**

thanks

*Edit 1 :*

My first solution was :

for Apache/PHP in vhost :

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV 'production'
```

for Ruby :

```bsh
export APPLICATION_ENV='production'
```

```
puts ENV['APPLICATION_ENV']
```

**However, this is two places to the same value... There are no solution to merge it in one place ?** *par exemple to use /etc/environment*

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `export` line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export APPLICATION_ENV='production'
```

Then, if you want to change it, run this from the terminal:

```
export APPLICATION_ENV='development'
```

Comment: PHP with Apache, can use this variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You could write the code you used in a function for both which accepts the variable name and the value.

Then just call your `custom_env_variable('APPLICATION_ENV','production');` when you need it. Basically suggesting a wrapper.